# What will happen if a SSL-configured Nginx reverse proxy pass to an web server without SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy

I use Nginx to manage a lot of my web services. They listens different port, but all accessed by the reverse proxy of Nginx within one domain. Such as to access a RESTful-API server I can use `http://my-domain/api/`, and to access a video server I can use `http://my-domain/video`.

I have generated a SSL certificate for `my-domain` and added it into my Nginx conf so my Nginx server is HTTPS now -- But those original servers are still using HTTP.

What will happen when I visit `https://my-domain/<path>`? Is this as safe as configuring SSL on the original servers?

Comment: Great question. Are the servers behind the NGINX reverse proxy on the same server, and are the firewall ports blocked, or are those other services on other servers, public to the Internet using HTTP?  I think the answers could possibly be different depending on these answers.

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks for complement. I just conceive a simple scene: All services can and only can serve users on the proxy tunnel of Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the goals of making sites be HTTPS is to prevent the transmitted data between two endpoints from being intercepted by outside parties to either be modified, as in a man-in-the-middle attack, or for the data to be stolen and used for bad purposes. On the public Internet, any data transmitted between two endpoints needs to be secured.

On private networks, this need isn't quite so great. Many services do run on just HTTP on private networks just fine. However, there are a couple points to take into consideration:

### Make sure unused ports are blocked:

While you may have an NGINX reverse proxy listening on port 443, is port 80 blocked, or can the sites still be accessed via HTTP?

Are the other ports to the services blocked as well?  Let's say your web server runs on port 8080, and the NGINX reverse proxy forwards certain traffic to localhost:8080, can the site still be accessed at http://example.com:8080 or https://example.com:8080?  One way to prevent this is to use a firewall and block all incoming traffic on any ports you don't intend to accept traffic on. You can always unblock them later, if you add a service that requires that port be opened.

### Internal services are accessible by other services on the same server

The next consideration relates to other software that may be running on the server. While it's within a private ecosystem, any service running on the server can access localhost:8080. Since the traffic between the reverse proxy and the web server are not encrypted, that traffic can also be sniffed, even if authorisation is required in order to authenticate localhost:8080. All a rogue service would need to do is monitor the port and wait for a user to login. Then that service can capture everything between the two endpoints.

One strategy to mitigate the dangers created by spyware is to either use virtualisation to separate a single server into logical servers, or use different hardware for things that are not related. This at least keeps things separate so that the people responsible for application A don't think that service X might be something the team running application B is using. Anything out of place will more likely stand out.

For instance, a company website and an internal wiki probably don't belong on the same server.

The simpler we can keep the setup and configuration on the server by limiting what that server's job is, the more easily we can keep tabs on what's happening on the server and prevent data leaks.

### Use good security practices

Use good security best practices on the server. For instance, don't run as root. Use a non-root user for administrative tasks. For any services that run which are long lived, don't run them as root.

For instance, NGINX is capable of running as the user www-data. With specific users for different services, we can create groups and assign the different users to them and then modify the file ownership and permissions, using chown and chmod, to ensure that those services only have access to what they need and nothing more. As an example, I've often wondered why NGINX needs read access to logs. It really should, in theory, only need write access to them. If this service were to somehow get compromised, the worst it could do is write a bunch of garbage to the logs, but an attacker might find their hands are tied when it comes to retrieving sensitive information from them.

### localhost SSL certs are generally for development only

While I don't recommend this for production, there are ways to make localhost use HTTPS. One is with a self signed certificate. The other uses a tool called [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) which lets you be your own CA (certificate authority) for issuing SSL certificates. The latter is a great solution, since the browser and other services will implicitly trust the generated certificates, but the general consensus, even by the author of mkcert, is that this is only recommended for development purposes, not production purposes. I've yet to find a good solution for localhost in production. I don't think it exists, and in my experience, I've never seen anyone worry about it.